# Scroll listview to bottom as fast as possible, but without skipping any items being viewed

Tags: android, scroll, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I need to make the listview scroll as fast as possible over all of its items, without skipping any of them.

I've found out that the [smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int,int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is very good, but it works only on API11+, and i wish to target at least API8.

I've also tried to use setOnScrollListener and similar solutions (setSelection, for example), but they either didn't work or they are too slow and doesn't reflect what an end user can do (fast fling over the listview). How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ListView source in API11+ and copy/paste it into a class that you extend from ListView.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java

Comment: do you think that the function i've chosen (smoothScrollToPositionFromTop) is the right way to go? anyway , i will check it out . thanks.